# time complexity of some specific system of $(n-3)/2$ linear equations with $(n-3)/2$ unknowns.

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, primality-test

let take **n** a **odd** integer greater than 3

if I have to solve this system of $(n-3)/2$ linear equations with $(n-3)/2$  unknowns to find some propriety about the number **n**,

here is formula for every equations in the system:
$(m^{2m-1}+m^0)x_1 + ... + (m^{2m-i}+m^{i-1})x_i + ... + (m^{2m-(n-3)/2}+m^{((n-3)/2)-1})x_{(n-3)/2}=\frac{(m+1)^n-m^n-nm^{n-1}-nm-1}{m^2}$

(the first equation is when m=1,the second when m=2 and so on until m=$\frac{n-3}{2}$)

the system will look something like this for a given **n**:

\begin{cases} x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{(n-3)/2} = 2^{n-1}-n-1\\ .\\.\\.\\(m^{2m-1}+m^0)x_1 + (m^{2m-2}+m^1)x_2 + ... + (m^{2m-i}+m^{i-1})x_i + ... + (m^{2m-(n-3)/2}+m^{((n-3)/2)-1})x_{(n-3)/2}=\frac{(m+1)^n-m^n-nm^{n-1}-nm-1}{m^2}\\.\\.\\.\\(\frac{n-3}{2}^{(2\frac{n-3}{2}-1)}+\frac{n-3}{2}^0)x_1 + (\frac{n-3}{2}^{(2\frac{n-3}{2}-2)}+\frac{n-3}{2}^1)x_2 + ... + (\frac{n-3}{2}^{(2\frac{n-3}{2}-i)}+\frac{n-3}{2}^{(i-1)})x_i + ... + (\frac{n-3}{2}^{(2\frac{n-3}{2}-\frac{n-3}{2})}+\frac{n-3}{2}^{(\frac{n-3}{2}-1)})x_{(n-3)/2}=\frac{(\frac{n-3}{2}+1)^n-\frac{n-3}{2}^n-n\frac{n-3}{2}^{n-1}-n\frac{n-3}{2}-1}{\frac{n-3}{2}^2}\end{cases}

Here is my main question:

What is the time complexity of this algorithm and what way can be use to find it?

Thank you very mutch.

Comment: The value of $m$ changes from one equation to the next but there are $m$ linear equations?  This does not sound reasonable.

Comment: Yes there is 1 equation for every value of m so an infinity but to solve the system limit m from 1 to the number of unknowns here it is (n-3)/2.If you pick n=5 there is two equations so the different values for m are {1,2}

Comment: I don't know how to explain better, there is no "fewer equations than variables".

Comment: the last equation I wrote (with the m) is a general formula to generate all equations in the system, you get equation 1 when m =1,equation 2 when m=2,....You need (n−3)/2 of them for the system to be solvable.

Comment: Ah, you’re right that there is not an imbalance of equations and unknowns.  But they both number $(n-3)/2$, not $m$.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks to you It is more clear for everyone!